# Stretchable UIButton Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

After following [this](https://coderwall.com/p/z9zgsw) tutorial, I understand how a strechable `UIButton` image works, but how large should I make the initial image (i.e. the one to be stretched)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Retina you should create image with 2px width and desired height.
Then, to have it strechable:

```
UIImage *stretchedImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

However if you have i.e. rounded corners, image should be wider. If the width of the corner is 8px, then overall width should be 2 * 8px + 2px = 18px. Then tutorial post you refered answers the rest.